# How to delete paperclip image in active admin on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, activeadmin

As of right now, a user can upload an image to active admin and also see a preview to this image. However, I am unsure how to add a delete button to this image.  Here's my code right now in Active Admin for content's input view:

```
 ActiveAdmin.register Content do

  form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
      f.input :image, :as => :file, :hint => f.template.image_tag(f.object.image.url(:thumb))
      f.input :remove_image, as: :boolean, required: false, label: "remove image"
    end
  f.buttons
 end
```

Model Content.rb

```
  attr_writer :remove_image

  def remove_image
    @remove_image || false
  end

  def before_remove_image
    if self.remove_image
      self.remove_image = nil
    end
  end
```

It is throwing me the following error when I check the boolean and attempt to update it:

```
RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error
Error:     /Users/LMo/Made/gluten-free-all/gluten-free/solr/data/development/index/segments_11 (No such file or directory)

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/LMo/Made/gluten-free-all/gluten-free/solr/data/development/index/segments_11 (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:233)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory$SimpleFSIndexInput$Descriptor.<init>(SimpleFSDirectory.java:70)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory$SimpleFSIndexInput.<init>(SimpleFSDirectory.java:97)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory$NIOFSIndexInput.<init>(NIOFSDirectory.java:92)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NIOFSDirectory.openInput(NIOFSDirectory.java:79)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.openInput(FSDirectory.java:345)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:265)
```

Answer (score 3):

I used this, but it's probably for an older version of ActiveAdmin. Maybe you can modify it though?

```
# In app/admin/model.rb
form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
  f.inputs do
    #...
    f.input :icon, :as => :file, :label => "Icon", :hint => f.template.(f.object.icon.url(:thumb))
      if (f.object.icon.present?)
        f.input :delete_icon, :as=> :boolean, :required => false, :label => 'Remove image'
      end
   end
   f.buttons
 end

# model.rb
attr_accessor :delete_icon
before_validation { self.icon.clear if self.delete_icon == '1' }
```

Comment: What does your model look like and did you need to add a column to your database for the boolean? Thank you!

Comment: Good point. I've added the fields from my model. Let me know if that works... Otherwise I'll keep searching.

Comment: Cool! Yeah, I may have even grabbed that off of a SO answer or somewhere on the internet a while ago. Glad it worked for you though!

Comment: Yikes. For some reason this isn't working on Heroku though. Thoughts?

Comment: Hmm not sure... Might need a bit more to go on. Doesn't look like that is the right location for the file?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help guys. This is the final working code...

**admin/product.rb**

```
f.input :image, required: false, hint: (("Current image:<br/>").html_safe + f.template.image_tag(f.object.image.url(:thumb))).html_safe
f.input :remove_image, as: :boolean, required: false, label: "Remove Image"
```

**models/product.rb**

```
attr_writer :remove_image

def remove_image
  @remove_image || false
end

before_validation { self.image.clear if self.remove_image == '1' }
```